# Can't read cookies in php using ssl

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ssl, cookies

I'm setting a cookie with PHP in www.mysite.com/CookieTest.php like so:

```
setcookie( "test", "value", time( ) + 259200000, "/" );
```

which works fine and I can see the cookie in the settings in Chrome.  I then try and read the cookie in www.mysite.com/Login.php like so:

```
if( isset( $_COOKIE[ "test" ] ) == false )
{
    echo "error";
}
```

which works fine with http, but not https.  The above always returns false, and when I try

```
print_r( $_COOKIE );
```

it prints an empty array, even though I can see that there are 5 other cookies set on my site's domain in Chrome.

I'm using ajax in jquery to make the request to both CookieTest.php and Login.php using https. I have set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and I'm not getting an error about the origin so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Read this 

[Reading cookies via HTTPS that were set using HTTP][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163828/reading-cookies-via-https-that-were-set-using-http

Comment: Please show the jquery ajax code

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll be busy all day today but I'll post more info later tonight

Answer (score 0):

Unless you used the `secure` flag while setting the cookie, your cookie should be sent with both http as https.

You need to double-check that your domain name is exactly identical in both cases. Check for example if you are not using `http://www.yourdomain/` (with `www.`) when setting the cookie and `https://yourdomain/` (without `www.`) when trying to read the cookie.