# https vs http reading cookie value in Jsp

Tags: java, jsp, http, cookies, https

I'm trying to read cookie value from a JSP:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
```

This seems to be working fine over http:// But fails to read over https:// call. Trying to see if I'm missing something here.

Comment: [Reading cookies via HTTPS that were set using HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163828/reading-cookies-via-https-that-were-set-using-http) ??