# ASP.NET Identity authentication is false when I switch from https to http

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.Net Identity and when I login in https login page and come to http home page I am seeing User.Identitiy.IsAuthenticated is false.

Is there someone who can explain why this is happening ?

Thanks

Ünal

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, since you've logged in from HTTPS, the cookie is *secure* and it won't be sent through insecure channels like plain HTTP.

What's the solution? There's no viable solution: **if you authenticate users and work with security data, your data exchange must go over the wire through HTTPS or you're absolutely open to man-in-the-middle attacks to steal your users' credentials (and other data like *claims*)...**.

Further reading: [Reading cookies via HTTPS that were set using HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163828/reading-cookies-via-https-that-were-set-using-http)

Comment: I changed entire pages to https :) thank you for your feedback.